# Hokuyo URG-04LX-UG01 Measuring area

Tags: hokuyo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am tying to use the Hokuyo node to get scan data from the Hokuyo laser URG-04LX-UG01.
When I visualized the laser scan in rviz, I only have a measuring area from -90° to 90°, and the measuring area of the laser should be 240°.

So I tried to change the parameters min_angle and max_angle of the hokuyo node but the maximum measuring area that I get is from -120° to +90°. Do you have any idea why I can't get data between 90° and 120° ?

Thanks for help,
Caroline

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/59087/hokuyo-urg-04lx-ug01-measuring-area/) by [CarolineQ](https://answers.ros.org/users/4109/carolineq/) on ROS Answers with karma: 395 on 2013-03-24

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What are the values you are setting as min- and max-angle? And are you setting them through dynamic reconfigure or in the launch file? Please provide some more information and the console output of the hokuyo_node.

Try setting them to some values slightly larger than the actual max-angles. Like -2.1 for min_angle and 2.1 for max_angle. If it is not too far off, the hokuyo_node should automatically set them to the maximum allowed values. (3 would be too much...)

---

Originally posted by [Ben_S](https://answers.ros.org/users/1072/ben_s/) with karma: 2510 on 2013-03-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Gav](https://answers.ros.org/users/3961/gav/) on 2013-03-25**:
+1 to this. The default behavior of hokuyo_node is to have min and max angles which are smaller than your scanner's field of view. You can either change the launch file or change them via dynamic reconfigure at runtime.

**Comment by [CarolineQ](https://answers.ros.org/users/4109/carolineq/) on 2013-03-25**:
I put the values you said and it works now.
Thanks for help.